# How to write a double diagonal arrow

Tags: arrows

How can I write a diagonal double arrow in Latex, I can only do it in vertical and horizontal directions.

Comment: You can search here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There are several horizontal and vertical double-headed arrow symbols out there. Which one do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by using the following:

```
\newcommand{\neswarrow}{\mathrel{\text{$\nearrow$\llap{$\swarrow$}}}}
\newcommand{\nwsearrow}{\mathrel{\text{$\nwarrow$\llap{$\searrow$}}}}
```

which allows me to use the commands \neswarrow  and \nwsearrow to print diagonal double arrows

Comment: Erh, what is `\text` suppose to do here? And `mathtools` provides `\mathllap`